# EPPlus: Cell displayed emty but return 0

Tags: c#, excel, pivot-table, epplus

There is an Excel file with a pivot table. In the file, I see empty cells, but I programmatically get the value "0"[image]

The contents of the cell I get in the standard way:

```
var text = ws.Cells[r, c].Text;
```

Is it possible to somehow get an empty string instead of "0" using EPPlus?

Comment: I've never used EppPlus.  However, in the Excel model of the world, the value of an empty cell is numeric 0.  However, if, in Excel, you have a formula like `=ISBLANK(A1)', the value will be true if the A1 cell is empty and false if it is not.  My guess is that EppPlus has a similar function.

Comment: What does `ws[r,c].Value` give you?  Is that screen shot before or after you have saved with Epplus?

Comment: @Ernie I’m not saving - I’m reading excel file. Property “Text” return “0”, property “Value” return 0.0 (double)

Comment: @Flydog57 unfortunately, no such functions in EPPlus

Comment: I see.  Ok, so, in your screen shot it looks like the cell value of the pivot table is actually "0" so Epplus would have to respect that.  Are you saying the the source of the pivot table cell is what is actually empty?

Comment: @Ernie yes, cell value empty in pivot table, but not empty in returned by EPPlus cell. I’m think that the reason - conditional formatting! But I’m don’t know how to handle this

Comment: Have you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36823687/can-epplus-distinguish-between-blank-cells-and-empty-text-cells-in-an-excel-work? It's the first link that popped up from a simple query

Comment: @Flydog57 unfortunately, it’s not at all there. In my case, it is a matter of conditional formatting, on the basis of which the excel changes the color of the text in the cell. But in the cell itself (in the file) the text color is stored without conditional formatting